# update if true and add new if false, criteria problem

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here is what i want: I'm making a code to generate invoices data automatically for me when i select month and year then click cmdbtn; but if customerID with the selected date ([Forms]![F_Reports_Slct]![MnthSlct]) and (....![YrSlct]) exists, then update the values instead of creating new record.

Everything here works fine except editing records if matched criteria..
my data is being recreated again when clicked.

I guess I have some problem with criteria.

Note that rsM and rsY are queries, and that the table's recordset ( rs ) has a primary key field with auto numbering [CrId].

```
Dim msg1 As Variant
Dim db As Database
Dim qdM As QueryDef
Dim qdY As QueryDef
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rsM As Recordset
Dim rsY As Recordset
Dim lngID As Long
Dim Mcr As String
Dim Ycr As String
Dim strCriteria As String

If IsNull([Forms]![F_Reports_Slct]![YrSlct]) Or IsNull([Forms]![F_Reports_Slct]![MnthSlct]) Then
 MsgBox "please enter data"
 Cancel = True
Else

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdM = db.QueryDefs("QC_MonthlyAm4CuID_Tr")
Set qdY = db.QueryDefs("QC_YrlyAm4CuID_Tr")

qdM.Parameters(0).Value = [Forms]![F_Reports_Slct]![YrSlct].Value
qdM.Parameters(1).Value = [Forms]![F_Reports_Slct]![MnthSlct].Value
qdY.Parameters(0).Value = [Forms]![F_Reports_Slct]![YrSlct].Value
qdY.Parameters(1).Value = [Forms]![F_Reports_Slct]![MnthSlct].Value

Mcr = qdM.Parameters(1).Value
Ycr = qdM.Parameters(0).Value

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("T_CrofServices", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsM = qdM.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsY = qdY.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

    
msg1 = MsgBox("sure?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Are You Sure?")

If msg1 = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True

ElseIf msg1 = vbYes Then

    If Not rsM.BOF Then
        rsM.MoveFirst
        
    Do Until rsM.EOF
        lngID = rsM!CuId & Mcr & Ycr
        strCriteria = rs!TrDtCuID = " & lngID"
        rs.FindFirst strCriteria
            If rs.NoMatch Then
                rs.AddNew
            Else
                rs.Edit
            End If
        rs![CuId] = rsM![CuId]
        rs![CollectorID] = rsM![CollectorID]
        rs![Amount] = rsM![MonthlyAm]
        rs![DateofCr] = rsM![DateofCr]
        rs![TrDtCuID] = rsM!CuId & Mcr & Ycr
        rs![TrDt] = rsM![DtTr]
    
        rs.Update
        rsM.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    End If
    
    If Not rsY.BOF Then
        rsY.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsY.EOF
        lngID = rsY!CuId & Mcr & Ycr
        strCriteria = "[TrDtCuID]=' & lngID'"
        rs.FindFirst strCriteria
            If rs.NoMatch Then
                rs.AddNew
            Else
                rs.Edit
            End If
        rs![CuId] = rsY![CuId]
        rs![CollectorID] = rsY![CollectorID]
        rs![Amount] = rsY![YrlyAm1]
        rs![DateofCr] = rsY![DateofCr]
        rs![TrDtCuID] = rsY!CuId & Mcr & Ycr
        rs![TrDt] = rsY![DtTr]

        rs.Update
        rsY.MoveNext
    Loop
    End If
    
    rs.close
    rsM.close
    rsY.close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rsM = Nothing
    Set rsY = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set qdM = Nothing
    Set qdY = Nothing
    
    
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation, "Succeed"

End If
End If
```

Comment: What event is code in? Have you step debugged?

Comment: yes it is in the strCriteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess I have some problem with criteria.

Yes. You must make up your mind, if you wish to use a Long or a String. Here, you are casting back and forth between these:

```
    lngID = rsM!CuId & Mcr & Ycr
    strCriteria = rs!TrDtCuID = " & lngID"
```

Also, it should read:

```
    strCriteria = "TrDtCuID = " & lngID & ""
```

Or, if you turn the ID into a string:

```
    strCriteria = "TrDtCuID = '" & strID & "'"
```

Comment: thank you for replying, I followed your suggestion, (which i tried before), and its giving a runtime error "3464 data type mismatch in criteria expression" on the (rs.FindFirst strCriteria) line..
Actually what I need here is to create a unique invoive id [for this customer] & [in this specific date selected], can you suggest any code to add a unique invoice id for invoices that are not yet created?
thanks

Comment: If TrDtCuID is a number type field, don't use apostrophe delimiters. Put field to search in quotes `strCriteria = "TrDtCuID = " & lngID`. Creating unique identifier is another common topic.

Comment: @gustav thank you for your help, the problem was with the parameters, now everything is solved :D.. I need one more thing, how can i count how many records were added and/or updated? (how many rsM and rsY were added into rs, and how many rsM and rsY were updated in rs.) if you please spare me writing a new topic and explain everything again.

Comment: note:  I've already done the "how many added", what i need is the number of records where any field's data changed, really changed.

Comment: OK, then please mark as answered. To count "really edited", compare all fields with their respective updating values, and only edit the record if at least one field value will be modified. That's the only method.